# Nginx - Passing parameters through to proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I'm new to nginx - am using Vouch proxy and trying to utilise its logout redirect: https://github.com/vouch/vouch-proxy#logout-endpoint-redirection

In my app I'm hitting a URL like: `mydomain.com/tools/app/logout?url={somevalue}`

Then in nginx I'm passing this onto vouch proxy with

```
location /tools/app/logout {
    proxy_pass http://vouch/logout;
}
```

However is it possible to pass that `?url={somevalue}` parameter too? Basically append to `proxy_pass http://vouch/logout`?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this one [here](https://medium.com/@shawnoy/how-to-setting-nginx-proxy-pass-and-forward-query-parameters-b59439f9c830)

Comment: The original query string will be appended automatically with the configuration you have in your question.

Comment: Thats right - I just released its adding it - thanks